# How to generate a list of certain subsets of x in r?

Tags: r

I want to generate a set in r which contains all of its subsets but not the set itself.

For example, say I have the set

```
    {1, 2, 3}
```

I want to generate the following list in r

```
    {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
```

However, the commands I am trying in r (powerset and set_power) are giving

```
    {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

I want to create a set which contains all of it's subsets.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can try with `combn`

Comment: Is it too hard to simply remove the one value that matches the input after you get the powerset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it by

```
    s <- c(1,2,3)
    powerSet(s)[-length(powerSet(s))]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you post it as answer, it should work. `powerSet` is not defined.

Comment: You are computing the power set twice, which is costly. Better to do `head(powerSet(s), -1)` or use `-2^length(s)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sets` package.
First, create set A:

```
library(sets)
A <- set(1,2,3)
A
{1, 2, 3}
```

Find the power set:

```
PS <- 2^A
PS
{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

And substract A from the power set:

```
B <- set_symdiff(PS,set(A))
B
{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
```